# Facing some issue in the Mobile Version

Tags: web, mobile, themes

Anybody tell me how to solve it...

[Mobile Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfVDe.png)
error page link : https://www.educatingpoint.com/home/

I am facing this issue on the Mobile only. I am not able to solve it, if someone guides me, it would be better for me...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Please try below CSS on the element -

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Comment: Please tell me, where do I add it??